# Which kind of map should I use?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I want to put some values in my `map<String,String>`. But I don't want to shift data with equal keys.
**Example:**

```
map.put("foo","some");
map.put("bar","thing");
map.put("foo","new");
```

Must return `foo-some,bar-thing,foo-new.`

But no `bar-thing,foo-new`.

Which kind of map should I use?

Comment: What do you mean by shift data?

Comment: `map.put("foo",5) map.put("foo",6) return (foo,6)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're trying to map multiple integers to single string key. It's possible but if you map your key to a `List`. The choice between a `HashMap` or a `TreeMap` would depend on whether you want to keep your entries sorted by key or not.

I believe that sorting is not what you're looking for; so, a `HashMap` would suffice.

```
public Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
```

Then you can add multiple values to the same key as

```
public void addToMappedList(Map<String, List<Integer>> map,
                                 String key, Integer value) {
    List<Integer> existingValues = map.get(key);
    if (existingValues == null) {
        existingValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        map.put(key, existingValues);
    }
    existingValues.add(value);
}

addToMappedList(map, "foo", 1);
addToMappedList(map, "foo", 2);
```

Here's how to go about removing individual values from the `List`. The *boolean* returned would indicate if the `value` was actually found and removed from the `List` or not.

```
public boolean removeFromMappedList(Map<String, List<Integer>> map,
                                         String key, Integer value) {
    List<Integer> existingValues = map.get(key);
    if (existingValues != null) {
        return existingValues.remove(value);
    }
    return false;
}

removeFromMappedList(map, "foo", 1); // true
removeFromMappedList(map, "foo", 3); // false
```

To remove the whole key and the `List` associated with it just use the `Map` directly

```
map.remove("foo");
```

Answer (score 4):

You will need a third party library as it is not in the standard runtime.  The Google Guava library is actively maintained and quite powerful.

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html